# Drawing primitive geometry in OpenTK?

Tags: opentk

I am using OpenTK library to embed an Opengl control onto C++ windows form. However, OpenTK doesn't support GLUT, so I cannot easily create primitive geometry such as cube, sphere, tetrahedron, etc. I actually plan to use all of the platonic solids, so recreating the whole dodecahedron triangles would waste me a lot of time. Is there a way to use GLUT in OpenTK? or is there an alternative functions to drawing platonic solids or primitive geometries in OpenTK?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using c++, why not using GLUT or similar libraries in the first place? - i am using OpenTK in purely C# applications. Otherwise OpenTK mimics the standart openGL API, with GL.Vertex3 you should be able to draw primitives just as usual with openGL. remember to swap buffers when you are done with a frame.

Comment: `OpenTK` has some primitive classes in their `examples` directory.

Answer (score 2):

OpenTK can only be used in context with C#. The problem is that there is no Glut library for C# because everybody uses C++ instead. Actually it is not OpenTK that does not support Glut, it's C# that doesn't.

Of course one could use C# with OpenTK and reference Tao.FreeGlut.dll which is a portation of the Glut library onto C#. That way you could use FreeGlut and would still have the advantage of OpenTK (which superseded Tao). OpenTK does not bring a FreeGlut portation itself like Tao does.

If you use C++, just get the regular freeglut.dll as discribed in this post: [glut and Visual Studio 2010](http://visualambition.wordpress.com/2010/08/12/glut-and-visual-studio-2010/)